# How to handle touch events for scaled ImageView?

Tags: android, imageview, android-imageview, android-touch-event

I need to handle touch events only for scaled/translated/rotated ImageView (only  resource part). Setting touch event on ImageView it handles the whole screen .not the resource part.
Any ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

By setting `android:adjustViewBounds` to true the ImageView will resize to the size of the resource. Of course the layout needs to be adapted to that. If you want to center for example you could place your ImageView inside of a RelativeLayout with `centerInParent`.